# Nested panels with background image?

Tags: java, swing

I have two panels defined like:

```
public class JPanel_with_BG extends JPanel
{
    private Image bg_image;

    public JPanel_with_BG(Image bg_image)
    {
        this.bg_image = bg_image;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (bg_image != null)
        {
            g.drawImage(bg_image, 0, 0, this);
        }           
    }
}
```

and,

```
public class MPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        // draw something...
    }
}
```

Then, I want to add the second panel over the bg_pnl. The top panel is smaller like bg_pnl.size = pnl + 2*padding.

```
MPanel pnl = new MPanel();
JPanel bg_pnl = new JPanel_with_BG(image);
int pad = 50;
bg_pnl.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(pad, pad, pad, pad));      
bg_pnl.add(pnl);
```

The problem is that what I'm drawing on the top panel is not visible. What I can see is only the background image. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Code seems ok. I tried this at my end and I can see a small area on my UI showing MPanel. You need to validate the size of your panel on which you are showing this component.

It might happen that the area is not visible because of the dimension of the window. Also a panel's default layout is flow layout and it arranges the components added on it based on their size and if they are really small, It might not be visible

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. Changing it to BorderLayout solves the problem. Also had to add pnl.setOpaque(false);. Thank you.